# NGINX redirecting subdomains to main domain

Tags: nginx, configuration, wordpress, website

I have 2 websites running on my server, a Wordpress site and a web-app running on port 8080. I want to point mysite.com and www.mysite.com to the Wordpress site and app.mysite.com to point to the webapp using NGINX.

I've made 2 separate configurations as below --

**mysite.com**

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;

        < ssl configs >

        include global/restrictions.conf;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

**app.mysite.com**

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name app.mysite.com;

        < ssl configs >

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $remote_addr;
        }

        location /stream/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.mysite.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

But when I try to access app.mysite.com, it's redirected to mysite.com. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. The mistake was very silly. The symlink I'd created for the webapp was wrong, so in effect there was configuration only for the main website.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you to use return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

at the place of return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

as $host will include all the server names and redirect everything to same host.